# Retrieving only nested documents that caused the hit in the first place with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index that looks something like this:

```
{
  field:'value',
  // ... more fields ...
  prices: [{"date":"2016-01-01", "nights":1, "price":300},...]
}
```

The `prices` array can contain around 10,000 entries per document.

I have a search query that will fetch all documents were the `date` and `nights` and `price` values all meet some requirements like "where date is X, nights is Y and price is between A and B"

When I fetch the results, I have to exclude the `prices` array from the source fields as it's way too big to be performant when retrieving 50 documents.

What I would like to do is retrieve the price entries that caused the doc to match in the first place.

Comment: 10,000 elements in an array sounds like a lot. Why not denormalizing and have 10000 documents? Anyway, if your price array is of `nested` type (which it should according to the query you're making), then you can use [nested inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) in order to see only the matching price sub-document.

Comment: I'm using ES to store precalculated pricing information, not sure how I'd denomalize it have 10,000 documents with largely the same info but with one price entry per doc? Though when I do the indexing job, the document count does go up hugely - so seems like ES is storing it nested inner hits is looking promising so far (stumbled upon it after asking the Q).